# file_get_contents returns HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: php, http

I want to get the contents of the url, when I used file_get_contents method it returns HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently. But in browser the link works fine.

I also tried curl function, but it is returns the same problem. The code is

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$a = curl_exec($ch);
if(preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $a, $r))
$xx = trim($r[1]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of you. I found the answer for my question.

```
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$buffer = file_get_contents($row['url'],false,$context);
```

Comment: Why does this work? Does supplying a User-Agent header prevent the site from redirecting?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    $ch= curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page_url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.google.com');  //just a fake referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $htmlContent= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I found answer but also I tried your answer. It is working perfect.

Comment: @KrishKowsi as per the accepted answer, `file_get_contents()` will not work for every website. some website have `allow_url_fopen` disable. so you will not be able to fetch contents from that website. `cURL` library will work perfectly. if you need any more help please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following because curl should be able to follow redirects

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);`